# Trouble getting jQuery to select an option from dropdown menu via an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm stuck trying to implement an HTML image map in my Rails 4 application.  The image map is of the human muscular system. The goal is for a user to click hotspots to choose target muscle groups.  The target muscle groups are in a drop-down menu, which works okay.  My objective is to improve user experience by associating drop-down menu options with hotspots on the image map.

The HTML for the muscle group collection (drop-down menu) is:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :muscle_group %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :muscle_group_id, MuscleGroup.order(:name), :id, :name, prompt: "Choose your target muscles", include_blank: false %>
</div>
```

Source code for the dropdown menu is:

```
<select id="strength_exercise_muscle_group_id"
 name="strength_exercise[muscle_group_id]"><option value="">Choose your target muscles</option>
<option value="11">Abs - rectus abdominis</option>
//more options
</select>
```

HTML code for the image map is:

```
<div class="Anatomy" style="position: relative;">
<%=image_tag("muscles_anterior_front view_pubic domain - Copy.png", :usemap => "#musclesfrontview") %>
<map name="musclesfrontview" style="height: 1100px; display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 919px;">
  <area shape="rect" coords="335,404,422,580" alt="Abs" href="#" id="map_abs"/>
  <area shape="default" href="" />
  //more areas
</map>
</div>
```

To test the image map, I created the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#map_abs").click(function(event){
    $('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id option:selected').val();
})
});
```

When I click the "abs" hotspot area in Firefox, nothing appears to happen.  Using Firebug, I am able to highlight the "abs" hot spot on the image, so the area coordinates on the image map appear to be correct.  I suspect there's a problem with my jQuery code.  For some reason the click event is not firing.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix my code to get my image map working?  I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$("#map_abs").click(function(){
    var absID = 11;
    var muscle_group = $("#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id option[value='" + absID + "']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close! You just need to set the value of the select with the abs value of 11 like so:

```
$("#map_abs").click(function (event) {
   $('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id').val(11);
});
```

If you are listening for change events on the selects, you can even trigger one when you change the value by doing `$('#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id').trigger('change')`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I tried passing the abs' option value of 11, but that didn't work.  Nothing happens ... no errors, no activity in the console.  Something else must be wrong with my code.  Any other ideas?  Appreciate your help!